# How to pass data from form in template to django views?

Tags: django

So I have this little project with messages and comments and i don't know how to save particular comment to particular message. Does anybody know how can i get message.id from template and send it to views.py?

```
        {% for message in messages_all %}
        <ul>
            <li>@{{message.host}}</li>
            <li>{{message.body}}</li>
        </ul>


        {% for comment in comments_all %}
            {% if comment.message == message %}
                <ul>
                    <li>{{comment.body}}</li>
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz">
            </form>
        {% endif %}


        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
form = AddComments()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddComments(request.POST)
messages_all = Message.objects.all()
comments_all = Comments.objects.all()

context = {
    'messages_all':messages_all,
    'comments_all':comments_all,
    'form':form
}
return render(request,'base/home.html', context)
```

Comment: You can use an hidden input with the value you want to pass to your form.

Comment: first of all, what's the form, is it for a new message or a new comment?

Comment: @AdilMohak its for a new comment

Comment: share your view related to rendering this HTML please

Comment: done, i edited post

Answer (score 0):

```py
def home(request):
    form = AddComments()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddComments(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('<your current view url>')
            
    messages_all = Message.objects.all()
    comments_all = Comments.objects.all()

    context = {
        'messages_all':messages_all,
        'comments_all':comments_all,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'base/home.html', context)
```